# Can we change the definition of negative exponents?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I am trying to understand the logic of negative exponents and I stumbled upon the video ["Negative Exponents"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pv1V6W_sGhM) by YouTuber JLC.

He says negative exponents are "defined". But why is it defined the way it is? Is there some kind of international agreement or some kind of international organization that maintains this definition of negative exponents? What if I make my own definition of negative exponents?

Please enlighten me, many thanks.

Comment: The extension is done in a fairly natural way. More precisely, the negative exponent is defined so that the following key property of the exponentiation continues to hold for integer exponents: $$a^{m+n}=a^m a^n.$$ There is a unique way of defining negative exponents so that this property holds for integer exponents, which is what you have learned.

Comment: By the way, if you have found other useful properties of some mathematical concept such that (1) it can be generalized beyond the realm the concept was originally defined, (2) the resulting generalization turns out to be useful, and (3) that generalization does not coincide with other proposed generalizations, then you may try promulgating your own version.

Comment: Generally speaking, you can define anything any way you like. Math is cool like that. Whether an idea attracts serious consideration depends upon how well it plays with other bits of math, how useful it is, etc. That said, some ideas garner attention even as curiosities. ... It's worth noting that exponentiation passes few stages of re-definition to accommodate ever-more-elaborate exponents (and bases): positive integer, zero, negative, rational, real, complex. The formal catch-all definition of $b^x$ is $\exp(x \log b)$, but that's not exactly going to help a youngster compute $3^{-2}$. :)

Comment: You could raise the issue for $x^0$ with $x\neq 0$ as well.  Often people seeing this for the first time think it must be $0$. But it is $1$ mostly because that is consistent with the rules of exponents noted above.  Students get caught up how to "calculate" it so it helps to view it as a definition.

Answer (score 1):

An expression such as $b^m$ is a notation whose meaning we get to choose. Already a long time ago it became clear that multiplying a number with itself was a common operation so we decided to give it its own notation. Note the following property of exponentiation for positive exponents: If $m$ and $n$ are positive integers, then $$ b^{m + n} = b^m \cdot b^n $$ since on both sides $b$ is multiplied with itself $m + n$ times.

When defining $b^m$ for negative integers $m$, we would like to keep this property of exponentiation for sake of consistency. For example, it should be true that $$ b^1 = b^{2 - 1} = b^2 \cdot b^{-1}. $$ By multiplying both sides of the equality with $\frac{1}{b^2}$, we are forced to define $b^{-1} = \frac{1}{b}$ in order to have an equality. In fact, using similar reasoning we can write $$ b^1 = b^{m + 1 - m} = b^{m + 1} \cdot b^{-m} $$ so that we are forced to define $b^{-m} = \frac{1}{b^m}$ if we want the additive property of exponents to be always valid.

EDIT: By following this line of thought you can come up on your own with the definition of rational exponents as well. You might know (or will learn in the future) that $b^{1/2}$ is used to denote the positive square root of $b$. For example, $4^{1/2} = 2$. The reason this definition is made is because we would like to have $$ b^1 = b^{1/2 + 1/2} = b^{1/2} \cdot b^{1/2} $$ for all positive numbers $b$. But this is the same as saying $b^{1/2}$ is the square root of $b$.

Comment: Yes. Let's also emphasize that the assumption that the base be positive is essential for rational exponents. If you try to extend the definitions to arbitrary nonzero real bases, you run into problems cause the composition law of powers no longer holds: $-1=(-1)^1=(-1)^{2/2}=((-1)^2)^{1/2}=1^{1/2}=1$ (contradiction).

Comment: The laws are special cases for positive real bases.